# Riemann-Stieltjes integral and function averages

Tags: probability, integration, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

$x,y:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are positive continuous functions. $y\left(p\right)$ is also monotone increasing (weakly). What are the conditions on $y$ so that there is $p \in [0, 1]$ for which

$$
 x\left(p\right) < \frac{\int_0^p x\left(p'\right)dy\left(p'\right)}{y\left(p\right)}?
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Have you any thoughts of your own on this problem?

Comment: I have a simple counter example and the intuition is pretty much clear to me, but I'm unable to formalize it so far.